# Django - name 'title' is not defined

Tags: django

An hour ago I started to make a web application, with Django. I watched this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qDwdMDQ8oX4

I'm following all his steps, but after changing some stuff, I've got an error which says

```
title is not defined in /about/.
```

[image: error message ib browser]

Here's my code for the route `/about/`. The code is equal to my other home page, but this one doesn't work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    {% if title %}
      <title>Django BLog - {{ title }}</title>
    {% else %}
      <title>Django blog</title>
    {% endif %}
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you post the code for your view?

Comment: Reword the question, fix image link, remove snippet from non-executable code block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in the traceback, title is not defined in your view. This happens because `title` is not wrapped in quotes so it assumes it's a variable.

Add the quotation marks like so  `'title'` and you should be fine.

So, you should change line 29 in views.py to

```
return render(request, 'blog/about.html', {'title': 'About'})
```